# "nested" table calls in JPA? (translate SQL to JPA)

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to convert this SQL into a JPA @Query call, and am struggling to understand how to handle multiple table calls in one JPA Query, specifically i am trying to return a Count of all the Users that are assigned to a Program.

The DB structure is shown:

[image: The DB structure is:]

The query I want to translate is:

```
SELECT *FROM  User WHERE id in ( SELECT user FROM UserProjectAssignment WHERE project in ( SELECT id FROM Project WHERE program = programId))
```

My current Query is:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u, UserProjectAssignment upa, Project p WHERE u.id = upa.project AND WHERE upa.project = (p.program = :programId)")
Long countUsersAssignedToProgram(@Param("programId") Long programId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need here is query with JOIN s
But one can form the query only if he knows the class structures.

You can change the mysql query like this

`Select user from User user join UserProjectAssignment upa on user.id = upa.userid join Project p on upa.projectId = p.id join program pgm on p.programId = pgm.id ;`